# Read from DataGridView

Tags: c#

I have dataGridView which contain column have checkbox
I need to read these rows who was checked 
How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
foreach (DataGridItem item in ItemsGrid.Items)
    { 
       boolean checked;
       checked =  item.FindControl("YourCheckBoxID").checked
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using binding DataGridView, you can get checked row collection in simple way.

```
            DataTable dtCustomers = (DataTable)dbgCustomers.DataSource;
            dtCustomers.DataSet.AcceptChanges();
            DataRow[] drChecked = dtCustomers.Select("columnName = True");
```

"drChecked" DataRow collection stores the checked rows of DataGridView.